# If you edit, input fields in a form with the "Tools Programmer" when submitting the form these values are assumed?

Tags: security, google-chrome

Perhaps i am being stupid by asking this just now, but...
I notice that if I edit the input fields with chrome tools programmer they are changed in the page...what about the security?

Anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always validate user input server side.

Comment: Sorry but i think i didn't understand...i'm not an expert :)

Comment: Any user can modify forms client side (in the browser) and submit fake, invalid, malicious, etc data. You always need to validate this data server side and return a form error if it isn't what you expect.

Comment: ok, but i have a script that puts some data like "290-277" (number-number) into a hidden input, how can i prevent user to change it to something else like "okEWWhhs/uyguy"??

Comment: There is no way to prevent users from modifying request data.